# Angular - Use static json for translations before the user authorized and after - use data from server

Tags: angularjs, factory, community-translations

Is it possible to use static json for translations before the user authorized and after - use data from server?

Comment: Could you give a try and solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) you can use `$translateProvider` (or `$translatePartialLoader`) to perform some [asynchronous loading](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

Works great for me and looks to solve what you are trying to do.

```
angular.module('contact')
.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('contact');
  $translate.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

used following:

```
 if('user is not logged in') {
 //get local file
   return this.getLocalTranslation(refresh, lang);
 }
 var deferred = $q.defer(); 
   else {
   $http({
     url: "" ;
     method: "GET"
   }).then(function(result) {
     if(result.data.success === 'true') { 
       console.log(result.data);
     } else {
       console.error(result.data.message);
       deferred.reject(result.data);
     }
   });
 }
```

if user is not logged in - then use local file, else call the source form server